# How to create connected lists?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a school project that wants me to design a restaurant app in C# Console project.
There is a part which confuses me a lot;

This restaurant has the following list of food in standard season

```
  -Pizza
  -Beef
  -Steak
  -Lasagna
```

However, note that this list is very upto change according to addition of
some special food during special times or events...

For food, customers may have make following additions .This list is also open to
extend in future.

```
  -Potatoes
  -Ketchup
  -Garlic Sauce
```

Here are some examples for customer requests

```
  -Beef with potatoes
  -Steak with double(2x) garlic sauce
  -Lasagna with Ketchup and Garlic Sauce
```

I defined a class to hold variables in properties as following;

```
public class Food: IFood
    {
        public string FoodName { get; set; }
        public int FoodQuantity { get; set; }
        public decimal FoodPrice { get; set; }
        public List<Addition> Additions { get; set; }
    }
```

I try to generate orders as following;

```
    cart.Items.Add(new Food{ FoodName = "Beef ", FoodQuantity = 1, FoodPrice = 7M, new Addition {AdditionName = "", AdditionPrice = "", AdditionQuantity = "" });
```

But it doesn't let me and gives me the following error;
'Invalid initializer member declarator'
Any ideas on how to do this in such a way that allows me to make a connection between an ordered food type and its additions?

Comment: You're passing a single Addition to the Additions initializer, but you've defined it as a list. You need to initialize it as a list. Also you should probably use a constructor here, since all properties are surely required to define a Food instance.

Comment: How am I supposed to connect the list with food type like in the sample user request?

Comment: You are doing it right, so it seems there is just the syntax issue. Initialize the `Additions` correctly. You could also use `enums` as `FoodType` or `AdditionType` as property in `Food` and `Addition` to replace the `string` Name, otherwise you will have `potatoes`, `Potatoes` and `Potatoe` later.

Comment: In reality you would also store the price somewhere else, it will not change between the orders. so you need a `FoodPrice` and `AdditionPrice` class. Then you could i.e. fill a `Dictionary<FoodType, FoodPrice>` which you can use to get the price for each food. Then the calculation becomes easy: `decimal finalPrice=foodPrices[FoodType]*FoodQuantity + additionPrices[AdditionType]*AdditionQuantity `

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is slightly wrong. First of all you didn't specify the name of the `Additions` property and secondly, you need to assign that a list, not just an individual item. For example:

```
cart.Items.Add(new Food
{
    FoodName = "Beef ",
    FoodQuantity = 1,
    FoodPrice = 7M,
    Additions = new List<Addition>
    {
        new Addition { AdditionName = "", AdditionPrice = "", AdditionQuantity = "" }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution!! Could you tell me how to calculate total price for this kind of structure please? Imagine this is a cart and I want to get the total price based on a food price and that food's additions' prices.

Comment: That is a new question. I suggest you try and figure it out before coming back here with a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In case of empty `Additions` list you should use:

```
cart.Items.Add(new Food { FoodName = "Beef ", FoodQuantity = 1, 
    FoodPrice = 7M, Additions = new List<Addition>() };
```

But it would be better if you define several constructors to ensure `Additions` list is always created (and you will not get futher errors in runtime):

```
public class Food: IFood
{
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    public int FoodQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal FoodPrice { get; set; }
    public List<Addition> Additions { get; set; }

    public Food(string foodName, int foodQuantity, decimal foodPrice) : this()
    {
        FoodName = foodName; 
        FoodQuantity = foodQuantity;
        FoodPrice = foodPrice;
    } 

    public Food()
    {
        Additions = new List<Addition>();
    } 
}
```

Now you can write something like:

```
 var food = new Food("Beef", 1, 7M);
 food.Additions.Add(new Addition { AdditionName = "Garlic", AdditionPrice = 0.1, 
      AdditionQuantity = 1 });
 cart.Items.Add(food);
```

Comment: Awesome solution, thanks a lot!!
Could you tell me how to reach inside of this Additions list and display its elements value please?Trying the following,I can't reach the list;
Console.WriteLine("Ordered beverages:");
            foreach (var item in cart.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Beverage Name: " + item.BeverageName);
                Console.WriteLine("Additions :");
                foreach (var addition in cart.Items.Additions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Addition: " + cart.Items.Additions);
                }
            }

Comment: Try to use `Console.WriteLine("Addition: " + addition.Name);` For the future it would be better to start a new question to avoid "garbage" in the comments)